# GitLab avoid duplicate jobs per environment

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, environment

I've the following GitLab CI:

```
stages:
  - firstStage
  - secondStage

-first-job:
  stage: firstStage
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ENVIRONMENT: 
        - test
        - production
  environment: $ENVIRONMENT
  script:
    - echo "firstStage $ENVIRONMENT"
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

-second-job:
  stage: secondStage
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ENVIRONMENT: 
        - test
        - production
  environment: $ENVIRONMENT
  script:
    - echo "secondStage $ENVIRONMENT"
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
```

My problem is that I want to execute all the jobs just for "test" environment. But right now if I don't execute the "first-job" for all the environments (test/production) I cannot execute the second-job for any environment.

I know that I can:

- Duplicate the jobs
- Remove the parallel matrix and put the environment as a variable
- Even change the allow_failure to true and this will allow me to execute the next stage

But I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to have the environments preconfigured and only execute the pipeline for one of them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While maintaining the parallel matrix, you might consider using the [`rules` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) to control job execution. For that, use a custom scripts to set an environment variable which can then be used in the `rules` condition.

```bash
[Updated GitLab CI Pipeline]
        |  
     setup
        |
   firstStage
    /      \
test    production
    |        | (via rules)
secondStage secondStage
```

That would be:

```yaml
stages:
  - setup
  - firstStage
  - secondStage

setup-job:
  stage: setup
  script:
    - export SELECTED_ENVIRONMENT=test
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: environment_variables

first-job:
  stage: firstStage
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ENVIRONMENT: 
        - test
        - production
  script:
    - echo "firstStage $ENVIRONMENT"
  environment: 
    name: $ENVIRONMENT
  rules:
    - exists:
        variables: $SELECTED_ENVIRONMENT == $ENVIRONMENT
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

second-job:
  stage: secondStage
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ENVIRONMENT: 
        - test
        - production
  script:
    - echo "secondStage $ENVIRONMENT"
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT
  rules:
    - exists:
        variables: $SELECTED_ENVIRONMENT == $ENVIRONMENT
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  needs:
    - first-job
```

An additional `setup` stage with a `setup-job` exports a `SELECTED_ENVIRONMENT` variable with the value `test`.
The `dotenv` artifact ([`artifacts:reports`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsreports)) in `setup-job` captures the exported `SELECTED_ENVIRONMENT` variable so it can be used in later stages.

In `first-job` and `second-job`, the `rules` keyword is used with the `exists` directive to check if the `SELECTED_ENVIRONMENT` variable matches the `ENVIRONMENT` variable for each job. That will make sure jobs in `firstStage` and `secondStage` will only run for the `test` environment, as per the `SELECTED_ENVIRONMENT` value set in `setup-job`.
The `needs` keyword in `second-job` ensures it waits for `first-job` to complete successfully before it is executed.

---

> I want to be able to execute/see the jobs of all the environments. But to choose only the execution of one of them now and another one in the future.
> Take for example I want to execute some common Jobs then deploy to test 2 (2 additional stages) and after that deploy to live if I want to (the same 2 additional stages). Is that possible?
>
> Meaning, I expect the same result as if I duplicated the jobs for each environment

So the goal would be to have visibility over all jobs across environments, but choose to execute jobs for a specific environment, either now or in the future, without duplicating job definitions for each environment.

One way to approach this would be to utilize the `rules` keyword along with a variable that can be set at runtime to control which environment the jobs should be executed for.

```yaml
variables:
  TARGET_ENVIRONMENT: "test"  # default environment; override at runtime if needed

stages:
  - firstStage
  - secondStage

first-job:
  stage: firstStage
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ENVIRONMENT: 
        - test
        - production
  script:
    - echo "firstStage $ENVIRONMENT"
  environment: 
    name: $ENVIRONMENT
  rules:
    - if: '$ENVIRONMENT == $TARGET_ENVIRONMENT'
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

second-job:
  stage: secondStage
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ENVIRONMENT: 
        - test
        - production
  script:
    - echo "secondStage $ENVIRONMENT"
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT
  rules:
    - if: '$ENVIRONMENT == $TARGET_ENVIRONMENT'
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  needs:
    - first-job
```

Define a global `TARGET_ENVIRONMENT` variable is defined which can be overridden at runtime to specify the environment for which jobs should be executed.
The `rules` keyword with an `if` condition in both `first-job` and `second-job` checks whether the `ENVIRONMENT` variable matches the `TARGET_ENVIRONMENT` variable. Only the jobs matching the target environment will be executed, but all jobs will still be visible in the pipeline view.
The `when: manual` keyword makes sure jobs are executed manually, allowing for control over when to execute jobs for a particular environment.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself properly. But I want to be able to execute/see the jobs of all the environments. But to choose only the execution of one of them now and another one in the future. Take for example I want to execute some common Jobs then deploy in test 2 (2 additional stages) and after that deploy to live if I want to (the same 2 additional stages). Is that possible?

Comment: meaning I expect the same result as if I duplicated the jobs for each environment

Comment: @Joan OK. I have updated the answer accordingly.